# How to know all the parameters passed to a cmdlet programmatically?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have customer cmdlet implemented in .net. I would like to know all the parameters user passed to it.

```
My-Cmdlet -foo -bar -foobar
```

Basically i would like to know that user executed this cmdlet with parameter foo, bar, foobar programmatically.

Looks like in script we can do it using:  $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf')

I need equalent of that in .net (c#)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I remember: $PSBoundParameters is just shortcut for $MyInvocation.BoundParameters:
$MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Equals($PSBoundParameters)
True

If you want to get the same information in cmdlet that *you* wrote, you can get it like that...:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Test
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "WhatIf", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
    public class GetWhatIf : PSCmdlet
    {

        // Methods
        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            this.WriteObject(this.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("WhatIf").ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The code is quick'n'dirty, but you should get the picture. Disclaimer: I'm not a developer, so I'm probably doing it wrong. ;)

HTH
Bartek

Comment: Need to also consider [`InvocationInfo.UnboundParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.unboundarguments%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for any not bound to a paramter (eg. when there is a parameter has `ValueFromRemainingArguments` true).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head,  you can't without having access to the code, unless you create a proxy command around the cmdlet (wrap the command with a function) and add your custom code to it. Another idea would be to check the last executed command in the console history or a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

Some how this.GetVariable for whatifpreference always returned false.

i worked around this by using myinvocation.buildparameters dictionary.

```
public bool WhatIf
{
    get
    {                                
        //if (this.GetVaribaleValue<bool>("WhatIfPreference", out whatif))
        return this.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("WhatIf")
            && ((SwitchParameter)MyInvocation.BoundParameters["WhatIf"]).ToBool(); 
    }
}
```

Regards,
Dreamer